Paketo: Running npm install following Python buildpack
We have added a static build step to our Python app which is triggered by npm build
We would like to implement this in our Paketo build so that the built client-side assets are available at runtime.
Based on the documentation it appears this should be possible by adding a --post-buildpack argument. However, when we tried adding this e.g.
pack build test_img --builder paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-full --post-buildpack paketo-buildpacks/npm-install@1.1.1 

It appears to no longer detect the Python dependencies e.g.
6 of 11 buildpacks participating
paketo-buildpacks/ca-certificates 3.6.7
paketo-buildpacks/node-engine     3.2.1
paketo-buildpacks/npm-install     1.4.0
paketo-buildpacks/node-run-script 1.0.16
paketo-buildpacks/node-start      1.1.5
paketo-buildpacks/procfile        5.6.8

Therefore the Python dependencies are no longer available in the PATH and the app fails to start up.
Is it possible to trigger npm build whilst retaining the Python layers in the buildpack?

Something is changing detection order and triggering the Node.js buildpack to pass detection first. If you run pack build -v -e BP_LOG_LEVEL=debug ... you'll get more output from detection and it might give you some clues as to why Node.js is passing detection instead of Python.

As an aside, you may need to create your own build group to make this work. The Paketo Python and the Nodejs buildpacks contain their own built-in order groups. Adding --post-buildpack will append to those order groups, but you may need more control, in which case you can use the -b flag to specify an exact list in order. The debug output I mentioned previously will show you what's not passing detection and you can then adjust the order group to provide/require what's missing, until you get an order group that gives the tools you need.
